# Select checkbox id with JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" class="africa" id="Senegal"/>Senegal
<input type="checkbox" class="africa" id="Camerun"/>Camerun
<input type="checkbox" class="europe" id="Spain"/>Spain
<input type="checkbox" class="asia" id="Japan"/>Japan
<input type="checkbox" class="europe" id="Germany"/>Germany
```

I have some checkboxes, How do I select the checkbox with the class that IS NOT africa?

The result should be Spain,Japan,Germany.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) in jquery:

```
var everythingElse = $('input[type=checkbox]').not('.africa');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery code using the **[not method](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** :

```
$('input:checkbox').not('.africa').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Comment: Using jQuery's selector extensions is not best practice.

Comment: @ Lucas: No. [Read the documentation for why](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/): *"Because `:checkbox` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:checkbox` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="checkbox"]` instead."* (The quotes around `checkbox` are unnecesary, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(.africa)').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/bbZuK/1/)